# Why do I lose panel title if I put paramters into config block in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

Here is a simple panel with a title "My Window":

```
Ext.define('MyApp.MyWindow', {
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    title : 'My Window',
    html : '<p>This is a test</p>',
    renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});
```

If I put the title into config block, the title will not show. Do you know why?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.MyWindow', {
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    config : {
        title : 'My Window',
        html : '<p>This is a test</p>'
    },
    renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because panel component already has the properties of title and html defined. You should not use the config option for any classes that extend Ext components. This is useful for creating your own classes. 
If you notice the example provided in "The Class System" guide uses this config but does not extend and Ext component. My guess is that since Ext Components use this system undercovers it is protecting itself.